# vertical transparent gap after particular UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I'm new in the world of IOS development. I have made UItableView that generates dynamic cells, according to the data available in my MutableArray now for example I have 4 cells

```
cell 1 with text
cell 2 with text
cell 3 with text
cell 4 with text
```

These above mentioned cells are coming with 1px separator space. I want to give transparent gap after my second cell. For example

```
cell 1 with text
cell 2 with text
.
.
.
cell 3 with text
cell 4 with text.
```

I have gone through lots of internet tutorials and help but couldn't find anything useful
here is the code that I tried..

```
    UIView *cellSeparator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320 ,1)];
    [cellSeparator setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [cellSeparator setContentMode:UIViewContentModeBottom];
    [cellSeparator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [cell addSubview:cellSeparator];
```

please It will be great if you can. Thanks

Comment: change the height of the third cell and add the subview to the third cell

Comment: how ? i mean i tried playing with tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: but it generates height of all the cells, how can i perform it any sample example please.

Comment: there is a delegate method called heightforRowAtindexPath . In that example write if(index path.row == ) { return 66;}

Comment: Can I post my comment as answer so that you can make it as correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a delegate method called `heightforRowAtindexPath` . In that write

```
if(index path.row == )
{
 return 66;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` on your table's delegate, to make cell 2 taller than the others.

Comment: I have this method in my code and i have defined hard coded height out there of 44. I tried playing with it but couldn't succeed since it generates height for every cell. So if i make any change for one it was also implemented on other.

Comment: return a different height if indexPath.row == 1